# Amazon Java SDK - Upload to S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the Amazon Java SDK to upload files to Amazon s3

Whilst using version 1.10.62 of the artifact aws-java-sdk - the following code worked perfectly - Note all the wiring behind the scenes works

```
 public boolean uploadInputStream(String destinationBucketName, InputStream inputStream, Integer numberOfBytes, String destinationFileKey, Boolean isPublic){

    try {
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(numberOfBytes);            
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(destinationBucketName, destinationFileKey, inputStream, metadata);

        if (isPublic) {
            putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        } else {
            putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.AuthenticatedRead);
        }

        final Upload myUpload = amazonTransferManager.upload(putObjectRequest);

        myUpload.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
            // This method is called periodically as your transfer progresses
            public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
                LOG.info(myUpload.getProgress().getPercentTransferred() + "%");
                LOG.info("progressEvent.getEventCode():" + progressEvent.getEventCode());
                if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE) {
                    LOG.info("Upload complete!!!");
                }
            }
        });

        long uploadStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long startTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long logGap = 1000 *  loggingIntervalInSeconds;

        while (!myUpload.isDone()) {

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeInMillis >= logGap) {
                logUploadStatistics(myUpload, Long.valueOf(numberOfBytes));
                startTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } 
        }
        long totalUploadDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - uploadStartTime;
        float totalUploadDurationSeconds = Float.valueOf(totalUploadDuration) / 1000;
        String uploadedPercentageStr = getFormattedUploadPercentage(myUpload);
        boolean isUploadDone = myUpload.isDone();

        if (isUploadDone) {
            Object[] params = new Object[]{destinationFileKey, totalUploadDuration, totalUploadDurationSeconds};
            LOG.info("Successfully uploaded file {} to Amazon. The upload took {} milliseconds ({} seconds)", params);
            result = true;
        } 
        LOG.debug("Post put the inputStream to th location {}", destinationFileKey); 
     } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
         LOG.error("AmazonServiceException:{}", e);
         result = false;
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
        LOG.error("AmazonServiceException:{}", e);
        result = false;
    }

    LOG.debug("Exiting uploadInputStream - result:{}", result);
    return result;
}
```

Since I migrated to version 1.11.31 of the aws-java-sdk - this code stopped working
All classes remain intact and there were no warnings in my IDE

However - I do see the following logged to my console

```
 [2016-09-06 22:21:58,920] [s3-transfer-manager-worker-1] [DEBUG] com.amazonaws.requestId - x-amzn-RequestId: not available
[2016-09-06 22:21:58,931] [s3-transfer-manager-worker-1] [DEBUG] com.amazonaws.request - Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Moved Permanently (Service: null; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 301 Moved Permanently; Request ID: D67813C8A11842AE), S3 Extended Request ID: 3CBHeq6fWSzwoLSt3J7D4AUlOaoi1JhfxAfcN1vF8I4tO1aiOAjqB63sac9Oyrq3VZ4x3koEC5I=
```

The upload still continues but from the progress listener - the event code is 8 which stands for transfer failed

Does anyone have any idea what I need to do to get this chunk of code working again?

Thank you
Damien

Comment: *"Note all the wiring behind the scenes works"* ... I'm not as confident as you are, on that point.  The error message suggests that you need to be passing a region for your bucket to a constructor, somewhere... and either you aren't, or you're passing a region that's inconsistent with the bucket's location constraint (region)... so the request is sent to, and arrives at, the wrong S3 regional endpoint, and #boom `301 Moved Permanently`.

Comment: I am using US Standard for the bucket location. Would you recommend setting a specific bucket. Haa trust me on your concerns but this has been running in a production environment now for near 2 years with various upgrades to the library - this is the first update to break it

Comment: Oh, I don't doubt that the wiring was correct at some point, but it isn't unheard-of for things to work as expected "by accident" until somebody somewhere removes an assumption you were relying on.  Unfortunately, I rarely use the SDKs -- my expertise is primary from working directly with the API endpoints and understanding what they expect and return, and that's the reason I feel reasonably confident that this is, somehow, endpoint-selection-related.  If you have a support contract, the request ID and extended request ID will probably enable support to trace the request and give you a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing it to this:

                `public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
                    LOG.info(myUpload.getProgress().getPercentTransferred() + "%");
                    LOG.info("progressEvent.getEventCode():" + progressEvent.getEventType());
                    if (progressEvent.getEventType() == ProgressEventType.TRANSFER_COMPLETED_EVENT) {
                        LOG.info("Upload complete!!!");
                    }
                }`

It looks like you are running some deprecated code.

In `com.amazonaws.event.ProgressEventType`, value 8 refers to `HTTP_REQUEST_COMPLETED_EVENT`

- `COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE` is deprecated
- `getEventCode` is deprecated

refer to this -> https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/event/ProgressEvent.java

Comment: Thank you - I will try this out and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I updated my versions of the S3 library, generated new Access Keys and also a new bucket

Now everything works as expected